# avoid memory leaks caused by new(new[])

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks, smart-pointers

I am working on an open-source library that has a memory leak in it. The library is a data streaming service built around boost::asio. The server side uses heap memory management system which provides memory to hold a finite number of `samples` while they wait to get pushed accross a tcp connection. When the server is first constructed, a heap of memory for all the old `sample`s is allocated. From this heap, after a `sample` is passed accross the socket, the memory is returned to the heap.

This is fine, unless all that pre-allocated heap is already taken. Here is the function that creates a 'sample':

```
sample_p new_sample(double timestamp, bool pushthrough) { 
    sample *result = pop_freelist();
    if (!result){
        result = new(new char[sample_size_]) sample(fmt_, num_chans_, this);
    }
    return sample_p(result);
}
```

`sample_p` is just a typedef'd smart pointer templated to the `sample` class.

The offending line is in the middle. When there isn't a chunk of memory on the `freelist`, we need to make some. This leaks memory.

My question is why is this happening? Since I shove the new sample into a smart pointer, shouldn't the memory be freed when it goes out of scope (it gets popped off of a stack later on.)? Do I need to somehow handle the memory allocated on the inside---i.e. the memory allocated by `new char[sample_size_]`? If yes, how can I do that?

Edit:
@RichardHodges here is a compile-able MCVE. This is highly simplified but I think it captures exactly the problem I am facing in the original code.

```
#include <boost/intrusive_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/lockfree/spsc_queue.hpp>
#include <iostream>

typedef boost::intrusive_ptr<class sample> sample_p;
typedef boost::lockfree::spsc_queue<sample_p> buffer;
class sample {

public:
    double data;
    class factory{
    public:
        friend class sample;
        sample_p new_sample(int size, double data) {
            sample* result = new(new char[size]) sample(data);
            return sample_p(result);
        }
    };

    sample(double d) {
        data = d;
    }

    void operator delete(void *x) {
        delete[](char*)x;
    }

    /// Increment ref count.
    friend void intrusive_ptr_add_ref(sample *s) {

    }

    /// Decrement ref count and reclaim if unreferenced.
    friend void intrusive_ptr_release(sample *s) {

    }

};


void push_sample(buffer &buff, const sample_p &samp) {

    while (!buff.push(samp)) {
        sample_p dummy;
        buff.pop(dummy);
    }
}

int main(void){
    buffer buff(1);
    sample::factory factory_;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        push_sample(buff, factory_.new_sample(100,0.0));
    std::cout << "press any key to exit" << std::endl;
    char foo;
    std::cin >> foo;

    return 0;
}
```

When I step through the code, I note that my delete operator never gets called on the sample pointers. I guess that the library I'm working on (which again, I didn't write, so I am still learning its ways) is mis-using the intrusive_ptr type.

Comment: you didn't showed the smart pointer type ...

Comment: this looks suspect as hell. Can you post an MCVE that compiles?

Comment: @RichardHodges coming Monday.

Comment: I see now that adding delete[] to the implementation of intrusive_ptr_release will do what I want.

Answer (score 2):

You are allocating the memory with `new[]` so you need to deallocate it with `delete[]` (on a `char*`). The smart pointer probably calls `delete` by default, so you should provide a custom deleter that calls `delete[]` (after manually invoking the destructor of the `sample`). Here is an example using [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).

```
auto s = std::shared_ptr<sample>(
  new (new char[sizeof(sample)]) sample,
  [](sample* p) {
    p->~sample();
    delete[] reinterpret_cast<char*>(p);
  }
);
```

However, why you are using placement `new` when your buffer only contains one object? Why not just use regular `new` instead?

```
auto s = std::shared_ptr<sample>(new sample);
```

Or even better (with `std::shared_ptr`), use a factory function.

```
auto s = std::make_shared<sample>();
```

Comment: assuming "sample" not overaligned, the default operator new invoked by the array new expression *will* return suitably aligned storage space, why do you think not ?

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes True. I've removed that part from my answer.

Comment: I didn't write this code, I'm just trying to fix it. I'm not sure why the original author did it this way.

Comment: @dmedine we cannot help if you don't tell the exact type of the smart pointer ...

Comment: @dmedine I've given you the solution. I've provided some examples now.

Comment: @JosephThomson Thanks for the excellent example. Unfortunately it appears that I misunderstood the problem in my OP. I voted it up because it is absolutely correct. I apologize for the ill-posed question.